# LM386 circuit design questions

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, lm386

Initially I trawled posts and forums (initially to debug some noise, squeals, and oscillations on some LM386 circuits I built). I've synthesised all of that knowledge and re-approached this IC, calculating a load of component values.

I get that there are lots of posts/questions about LM386. I'm asking if I've stitched all of the answers together properly and therefore wanted to run this past some people more knowledgable than myself. I've not breadboarded this yet as I don't have all the components and was looking for some feedback before I order.

Also, please note that I am a complete amateur here. I’m more than capable of plugging numbers into calculations but I don’t fully understand all of the concepts behind these. I’d never heard of Xc for example.

Here's the datasheet for anyone who needs it - https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf

Here's a schematic:
[image: LM386 Schematic]

So, first of all, C1, the input DC blocking capacitor. The 10K volume pot in parallel with the IC's 50K input impedance results in 8.3K input resistance.

I'm aiming for Xc lower than 8.3K/10 at 100hz (this is low enough for my application, 20hz seems excessive for me). A 2.2µF cap gives Xc of 0.72KΩ at 100Hz so this seems good to me. This is higher than any other LM386 amplifier design I’ve seen online though (ranging from 47nF to 1µF)?

Next, C2. I went by the datasheet which shows 50µF as the best frequency response (Fig 2. Power Supply Rejection vs Frequency). The graph is for 6V supply though and I’m using 9V so I’m unsure what impact that might have. Again, 50µF is higher than the e.g. 0.1µF I’ve seen elsewhere.

For C3, I’m connecting to a miniature 8Ω speaker (well actually vibration speaker element so a speaker coil driver without the cone). The chip’s output resistance is 0.1Ω so I have a total output resistance of 8.1Ω. To work out the capacitor I’m aiming for Xc less than 8.1Ω/10 at 100Hz. A 2,200µF cap gives me 0.72Ω at 100Hz. This is much higher than used in many other circuit. Size and cost seems a more likely factor behind this and I have seen 2,200µF recommended elsewhere.

C4 and R1 form part of the Zobel network. Rather than take the standard values seen in many circuits (generally 10R and 47nF) I calculated these. My speaker has a voce coil/DC resistance of 7.4Ω. recommended resistor value is this times 1.25 and so 9.25Ω. 10Ω resistor is fine. For the cap the calculation is Le (voice coil inductance) / R (9.25Ω above) * R (well R squared but I can’t do superscript 2). Le for my speaker driver is 0.06mH. I dived this by 1000 to get Henries (and multiplied the result of the calculation by 1000000 to get µF) resulting in 0.61µF. I understand that going higher should be fine so a 1µF cap is an easy value.

C5 and C6 are power supply filtering/decoupling. I couldn’t find a source to calculate this so went with a range of advice and settled on 100µF and 0.1µF.

I’m leaving pins 1 and 8 open as 20 gain should be enough for me.

I’m using the inverting input (pin 2) as it’s suggested that it sounds better.

As my calculations result in some higher value capacitors than I’ve generally seen I’ve plumped for some polarised elctrolytics where I don’t usually see them (C1 and C2) so I’m unsure about polarity here.

Phew, so that’s the schematic. I’ve also laid out a board design based upon all of this and taking into account best practice I’ve seen. There’s especially an issue with keeping in, out, and power grounding separated and so I’ve done my best here at star grounding on pin 4 (any good?). I’m using non-standard symbols (heavily drawn from Peter Blasser’s paper circuits) but the one’s which should be hardest to figure out are the circles with black triangles next to them. These are for the input and output jack grounds. Oh, and the weird 'power obelisk' to the right is where the 9V battery supply will connect.

[image: LM386 PCB layout]

I appreciate that there’ll be a range of factors such as space and cost and so I’m just aiming for something more ‘ideal’ than practical at this stage.

So, anyone who actually understands all of this properly able to comment?

Thanks for your time.(

Comment: It's hard for me to reconcile "artistically placed components with no current return paths underneath" with "best practices"; let's face it, even if this is low frequency by any means, best-practice circuit boards look rather regular and boring. (This matters a bit, but not too much: the LM386, even in a perfect layout, is a really really crappy amplifier, and you'd better be investing your time and external components (which are more expensive than the amplifier here, quickly) in something that isn't per se terrible)

Comment: Why is there an issue keeping the grounds separated? I don't see why doing that would be desirable at all?

Comment: Looks to me like you're doing this a bit too much "from scratch" and that leaves you with lots and lots of uncertainties, doubts and **overthinking**. My suggestion: **look at what others do**. Study some projects that also use the LM386. Order a **module** which uses the LM386 (these modules are very cheap and just work). There are many small details you don't know about (yet) and taking that all into account at your skill level is impossible. So just copy what other do. With more experience you'll understand why things are done like that.

Comment: @MarcusMüllerfiar point about the 'artistic' pcb layout. At the moment 'current return paths' are beyond me.

Comment: @MarcusMüllerre: grounding. e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lBGE5lwbruE (there are others but I can't find them right now)

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie thanks for taking the time but I've built numerous LM386 circuits in the past, this isn't entirely new to me (though I don't claim to be more than a hobbyist). Having a stab at calculating values etc. is a way of trying to understand the design decisions made by others. What details don't I know about yet? Just pointing out they exist isn't exactly helpful. I've tried to be realistic and humble about my knowledge and background (incidentally art rather than electronics engineering) but please don't assume my skills and knowledge.

Comment: *What details don't I know about yet?* The way that you layout the circuit, component placing, using thin wires to connect everything (instead of using a ground plane for example), not thinking about the "current return paths" this could cause the signal to the speaker finding its way back to the input, giving you an **oscillator** (as opposed to an amplifier). *I've built numerous LM386 circuits in the past* Then why ask so much and doubt everything now? I don't understand.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie so PCB layout stuff more than values/calculations? For PCB, I thought about component placement (i.e. power filtering near chip, short in/out paths.) and I checked online calculator for trace width. I've not figured out ground plane in Osmond (I tried it but didn't work as expected so need to look into that more). Thanks, I'll try and get my head around current return paths. Why ask so much and doubt everything now... because I'm trying to go deeper into it. Asking questions seems like a good way of learning. Those past circuits never seemed to work as well as promised.

Answer (score 3):

First problem is that usually a PP3/LR61 type 9V battery can't provide enough current to power the amplifier to drive an 8 ohm speaker.

Otherwise the component values are pretty sane, except for the Zobel capacitor. 1 uF with 10 ohms Zobel network is an RC filter with 3dB point at 16kHz, which is well within audio band. It means that at that frequency you have both the speaker and the Zobel network loading the output, so extra power is needed. The original Zobel network is made to stabilize the output by having the 3dB point at near 300kHz which is the bandwidth of the chip.

The 2200uF output cap is kind of overkill, but with a 8 ohm speaker it does provide 3dB point at 9HZ, which means the phase will be linear down to 90Hz or so.

Just don't expect Hi-Fi quality out of it, especially when powered with a 9V battery.

Comment: They used to sell little speaker boxes with an LM386, a small 8 ohm speaker, and a 9V battery inside.  They'd run for hours, no problem.  The battery isn't the limit on the sound quality of the LM386, it is the LM386 itself.

Comment: @justme Thanks, that's interesting about the zobel network. I used one of a handful of pages I could find about calculating the zobel networks e.g. https://audiojudgement.com/impedance-equalization-circuit-zobel-network/ You've appear to have approached it as an RC lowpass filter? Do you know anything about the difference in approach and pros\cons.

Comment: The point is not to make the chip have a constant impedance load based on your specific speaker, but to just have enough high frequency load so it is stable. We don't know why and how the datasheet ended up with these values, but they would not suggest these values if they were poor values.

Comment: @Justme cool, thanks.